# What causes <div> to be taller than its children?

Tags: css

What causes the div `.btn-group` to be taller than all its child elements?

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pastaclub/jdn58g40/) for applied CSS and visual demonstration.

```
<div class="top-box p-sm">
  <div role="toolbar" class="btn-toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group red">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
      <div class="tooltip-button-helper" aria-describedby="ttRename">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
          style="pointer-events: none;">Rename</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.btn-group {
  background-color: red;
}

.tooltip-button-helper {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

// fix styling of buttons in ButtonGroups and ButtonToolbars which got broken by inserting another div
.btn-toolbar>.tooltip-button-helper>.btn {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.btn-group>.tooltip-button-helper:first-child:not(:last-child)>.btn:not(.dropdown-toggle) {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.btn-group>.tooltip-button-helper:last-child:not(:first-child)>.btn,
.btn-group>.tooltip-button-helper:not(:first-child)>.dropdown-toggle {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.btn-group .btn+.tooltip-button-helper>.btn,
.btn-group .tooltip-button-helper>.btn+.btn-group,
.btn-group .tooltip-button-helper>.btn-group+.btn,
.btn-group .tooltip-button-helper>.btn-group+.btn-group {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="top-box p-sm">
  <div role="toolbar" class="btn-toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
      <div class="tooltip-button-helper" aria-describedby="ttRename">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="pointer-events: none;">Rename</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
What causes the div .btn-group (with the dark red background) to be taller than its child elements?
```

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of the markup that causes the problem here, not a third party web site that can change or disappear tomorrow. Only showing your HTML is of no help to anyone to solve your problem.

Comment: @Rob: I thought about that too. But the example relies on bootstrap (which brings tons of CSS rules) and I also have a number of rules in the fiddle, most of which are unrelated. The problem could be caused by any rule of all of those, and I didn't know by which one. So in a case like that, what am I supposed to include?

Comment: This is an issue caused by losing site of the fundamentals and relying on other people's code. I believe such questions are better suited for their forums and not SO cause the code requirements are far larger than can be done if one just stuck to the basics.

Comment: @travelboy I edited your post with how you should have added the code to your post. There is a snippet tool (`<>`) in the post editor where you can include code, and you reference external libraries by either putting the script/link tag in the HTML or using the "add external library" button. It's basically a simplified version of jsfiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the vertical align on your `inline-block` elements. If you set them to `vertical-align: top` it will get rid of the space at the bottom. https://jsfiddle.net/jdn58g40/3/

```css
.btn-group {
  background-color: red;
}

.tooltip-button-helper {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

// fix styling of buttons in ButtonGroups and ButtonToolbars which got broken by inserting another div
.btn-toolbar>.tooltip-button-helper>.btn {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.btn-group>.tooltip-button-helper:first-child:not(:last-child)>.btn:not(.dropdown-toggle) {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.btn-group>.tooltip-button-helper:last-child:not(:first-child)>.btn,
.btn-group>.tooltip-button-helper:not(:first-child)>.dropdown-toggle {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.btn-group .btn+.tooltip-button-helper>.btn,
.btn-group .tooltip-button-helper>.btn+.btn-group,
.btn-group .tooltip-button-helper>.btn-group+.btn,
.btn-group .tooltip-button-helper>.btn-group+.btn-group {
  margin-left: -1px;
}

button, .tooltip-button-helper {
  vertical-align: top !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="top-box p-sm">
  <div role="toolbar" class="btn-toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
      <div class="tooltip-button-helper" aria-describedby="ttRename">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="pointer-events: none;">Rename</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
What causes the div .btn-group (with the dark red background) to be taller than its child elements?
```